# ubuntu 18.04 offers obsolete version of varnish in official repo

Tags: varnish, ubuntu-18.04

As you know, Ubuntu 18.04 was release less than 2 months ago. When I tried to install varnish from the official ubuntu repo, it offered version 5.2.1-1.
However, on the varnish site it says that 5.2.1 is "retired", as you can see here:
https://varnish-cache.org/releases/

Am I missing something? Does it happen often? What's the point of introducing the next version of varnish in the new repos, given that varnish 4.1.10 was release of in April 2018 and it's still supported?

Comment: That happens all the time with open source projects moving forward with new releases containing both new functionality and bug and security fixes. Distributions that aim to provide a long term stable platform usually counter that by picking a specific release and will backport critical bug fixes and security  to their version. Red Hat explains that pretty well here: https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting and the same applies to Ubuntu LTS releases.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that that version of varnish is going to be ok for production, as long as canonical offers it in its official repos? And that I might even receive updates later on for it?

Comment: Yes. Canonical and the Ubuntu community will provide security updates for as logs as Ubuntu 18.04 is supported.

Comment: After going through various scenarios and understanding how it works, I've drawn the conclusion that this is COMPLETELY wrong. You should never assume that packages on the official ubuntu repo are, by default, supported and regularly updated.
Ubuntu 16.04 delivers varnish 4.1.1 - a buggy version for which pass doesn't seem to be working and pipe works but extremely slowly. Until you manually update to 4.1.10, you won't get rid of the bug.
Ubuntu 18.04 comes with varnish 5. Again, buggy, regular interruptions, a few times a day. Fixed it by upgrading to varnish 5.
Very dangerous supposition!

Comment: In the previous comment I meant to say that I fixed it by upgrading to varnish 6, of course.